# Docker image prune -a command not reclaiming any space

Tags: docker

Why is the `docker image prune -a` command not reclaiming any space?

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

No containers running.

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
awsdevenv    latest    41d1e7913346   2 minutes ago    1.57GB
<none>       <none>    da7eb8c6161b   52 minutes ago   1.57GB
```

My (probably incorrect) understanding is that `docker image ls` shows 1.57GB x 2 used space for these images.

```
$ docker image prune -a
WARNING! This will remove all images without at least one container associated to them.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Images:
deleted: sha256:da7eb8c6161b53f9c93e2cf88a53d48dd44e412302c940b34f0efc680da22ebc
untagged: awsdevenv:latest
deleted: sha256:41d1e7913346f59695b573ef04b87f6d05d35333bd07839a5a5b0295e57fa274

Total reclaimed space: 0B
```

But the total reclaimed space is the shown as 0.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker container ls` shows only running containers. Use `docker container ls -a` to show running and stopped containers. ([Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_ls/))

Now you should see the containers that still exist.